# Plot 3D vectors (quiver plot) using data from 2 separate data files

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have 2 separate data files with multiple entries like so:

```
File1.dat          File2.dat
x1 y1 z1           x2 y2 z2
x1 y1 z1           x2 y2 z2
...                ...
x1 y1 z1           x2 y2 z2
```

Is there a way to plot 3D vectors from the point in row 1 of File 1: (x1 y1 z1) to the point in row 1 of File 2: (x2 y2 z2) for all the entries? I guess this is called a quiver plot

Answer (score 5):

You can plot a `quiver` plot with data from a single file doing

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
x y z u v w
0 1 2 3 4 5 
1 2 3 4 5 0
2 3 4 5 0 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
]
\addplot3 [blue,-stealth,samples=10,quiver,quiver/.cd,u=\thisrow{u},v=\thisrow{v},w=\thisrow{w}] table {data.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So I guess one way on doing this would be to gather the two files together prior plotting.

**EDIT** Here is a starting point to help lerge the two datasets into one table using `pgfplotstable`, building the table works but not the plotting. I have to figure why

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{dataxyz.txt}
x y z
0 1 2 
1 2 3
2 3 4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{datauvw.txt}
u v w
3 4 5 
4 5 0
5 0 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
% loads dataxyz.txt into \outputxyz
\pgfplotstableread{dataxyz.txt}{\outputxyz}
% transposes \outputxyz
\pgfplotstabletranspose[input colnames to={}]{\outputxyz}{\outputxyz}
% concatenates \outputxyz to \output
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\output}{\outputxyz}
% loads datauvw.txt into \outputuvw
\pgfplotstableread{datauvw.txt}{\outputuvw}
% transposes \outputuvw
\pgfplotstabletranspose[input colnames to={}]{\outputuvw}{\outputuvw}
% concatenates \outputuvw to \output
\pgfplotstablevertcat{\output}{\outputuvw}
% transposes output
\pgfplotstabletranspose[input colnames to={}]{\output}{\output}

% display output
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\outputxyz
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\outputuvw
%\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\output

% Working plot
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[]
\addplot3 [blue,-stealth,quiver,quiver/.cd,u=\thisrow{3},v=\thisrow{4},w=\thisrow{5}] table[] {\output};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT 2** <sub><sup>by [Max](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/74459/max)</sup></sub>
In my [initial comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446526/plot-3d-vectors-quiver-plot-using-data-from-2-separate-data-files/446527#comment1121674_446527) I pointed out that the plot works when using the `input colnames to={}` option for all transpose actions, but this way you lose the column names. If you use `colnames from=colnames` and `input colnames to={}` *only* for the last transpose, the column names are kept, and the plot can be made as if the two tables were in one file.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{dataxyz.txt}
x y z
0 1 2 
1 2 3
2 3 4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{datauvw.txt}
u v w
3 4 5 
4 5 0
5 0 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    % loads dataxyz.txt into \outputxyz
    \pgfplotstableread{dataxyz.txt}{\outputxyz}

    % transposes \outputxyz
    \pgfplotstabletranspose{\outputxyzT}{\outputxyz}

    % concatenates \outputxyz to \output
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputT}{\outputxyzT}

    % loads datauvw.txt into \outputuvw
    \pgfplotstableread{datauvw.txt}{\outputuvw}

    % transposes \outputuvw
    \pgfplotstabletranspose{\outputuvwT}{\outputuvw}

    % concatenates \outputuvw to \output
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputT}{\outputuvwT}

    % transposes output
    \pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=colnames,input colnames to={}]{\output}{\outputT}

    \begin{tabular}{rr}
           As read xyz: & \mbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\outputxyz}  \\[1cm]
        Transposed xyz: & \mbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\outputxyzT} \\[1cm]
           As read uvw: & \mbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\outputuvw}  \\[1cm]
        Transposed uvw: & \mbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\outputuvwT} \\[1cm]
         Concatenation: & \mbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\outputT}    \\[1cm]
                 Final: & \mbox{\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]\output}     \\[1cm]
    \end{tabular}



    % Working plot
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=x,ylabel=y,grid=both]
    \addplot3 +[
        blue,
        -stealth,
    %    x=\thisrow{x},
    %    y=\thisrow{y},
    %    z=\thisrow{z},
        quiver,
        quiver/.cd,
            u=\thisrow{u},
            v=\thisrow{v},
            w=\thisrow{w}
        ] table {\output};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This results in

[image]

And the plot is

[image]

**Edit 3** <sub><sup>by [Max](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/74459/max)</sup></sub>
A small edit to show how to use this to draw from `(x1,y1,z1)` to `(x2,y2,z2)`, with some very simple example coordinates:

[image]

The important changes are that the coordinates are named as in your question, and the expression for `u`, `v`, and `w` are changed to:

```
u={\thisrow{x2}-\thisrow{x1}},
v={\thisrow{y2}-\thisrow{y1}},
w={\thisrow{z2}-\thisrow{z1}},
```

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=6cm,compat=1.16}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{filecontents*}{dataxyz.txt}
x1 y1 z1
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{datauvw.txt}
x2 y2 z2
1 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 1
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

    % loads dataxyz.txt into \outputxyz
    \pgfplotstableread{dataxyz.txt}{\outputxyz}

    % transposes \outputxyz
    \pgfplotstabletranspose{\outputxyzT}{\outputxyz}

    % concatenates \outputxyz to \output
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputT}{\outputxyzT}

    % loads datauvw.txt into \outputuvw
    \pgfplotstableread{datauvw.txt}{\outputuvw}

    % transposes \outputuvw
    \pgfplotstabletranspose{\outputuvwT}{\outputuvw}

    % concatenates \outputuvw to \output
    \pgfplotstablevertcat{\outputT}{\outputuvwT}

    % transposes output
    \pgfplotstabletranspose[colnames from=colnames,input colnames to={}]{\output}{\outputT}

    % Working plot
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \begin{axis}[xlabel=x,ylabel=y,zlabel=z,grid=both]
            \addplot3 +[
                blue,
                -stealth,
                x=\thisrow{x1},
                y=\thisrow{y1},
                z=\thisrow{z1},
                quiver,
                quiver/.cd,
                    u={\thisrow{x2}-\thisrow{x1}},
                    v={\thisrow{y2}-\thisrow{y1}},
                    w={\thisrow{z2}-\thisrow{z1}},
                ] table {\output};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you change all `\pgfplotstabletranspose` to `\pgfplotstabletranspose[input colnames to={}]`, and the `\thisrowno`s to `\thisrow`, it should work.

Comment: I edited your answer to include a way to keep the headers. If you do not agree, please feel free to rollback.