# Anyone have any Idea on how to plot flow streamline from velocity data using pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have velocity data from my simulation, anyone have experience in plotting flow streamlines using pgfplot.
I have data in the form;
x     y      z      u      v      w

Comment: With quiver plots it should be possible.

Comment: Here is an explicit example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/446527/121799